# Trouble reshaping--data destroyed somewhere in the process

Tags: r, reshape2

I've got data with the following form:

```
    brt_id          ADDRESS             OWNERNAME year PRINCIPAL INTEREST PENALTY OTHER        TOTAL LIEN STATUS
1 11000600 00108 WHARTON ST PRUSINOWSKI JOSEPHINE 2001         0        0       0     0     0            
2 11000600 00108 WHARTON ST PRUSINOWSKI JOSEPHINE 2002         0        0       0     0     0            
3 11000600 00108 WHARTON ST PRUSINOWSKI JOSEPHINE 2003         0        0       0     0     0            
4 11000600 00108 WHARTON ST PRUSINOWSKI JOSEPHINE 2004         0        0       0     0     0            
5 11000600 00108 WHARTON ST PRUSINOWSKI JOSEPHINE 2005         0        0       0     0     0            
6 11000600 00108 WHARTON ST PRUSINOWSKI JOSEPHINE 2006         0        0       0     0     0
```

I want to reshape it "wide by year" (as is my instinct from similar exercises in STATA), so that I get variables like `PRINCIPAL_2001`, `PRINCIPAL_2002`, etc.

However, when I run:

```
data2m<-melt(data2, id=c("brt_id", "year"))
data2c<-dcast(data2m, brt_id+year~...)
```

The resulting data (which should be identical to the original data) looks like:

```
    brt_id year ADDRESS OWNERNAME PRINCIPAL INTEREST PENALTY OTHER TOTAL LIEN STATUS
1 11000600 2001       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
2 11000600 2002       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
3 11000600 2003       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
4 11000600 2004       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
5 11000600 2005       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
6 11000600 2006       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
```

I get a warning message when I melt the data:

```
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped
```

And another when I cast the data:

```
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
```

It looks like the problem is happening with casting, as a peek at the melted data seems fine:

```
            brt_id year variable      value
70000000 621506800 2005     LIEN           
70000001 621506800 2006     LIEN           
70000002 621506800 2007     LIEN           
70000003 621506800 2008     LIEN           
70000004 621506800 2009     LIEN
```

The result is similar (though worse) if I use `acast`:

```
              ADDRESS OWNERNAME PRINCIPAL INTEREST PENALTY OTHER TOTAL LIEN STATUS
11000600_2001       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
11000600_2002       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
11000600_2003       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
11000600_2004       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
11000600_2005       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
11000600_2006       1         1         1        1       1     1     1    1      1
```

Any idea what might be going wrong here? I also lose one observation when trying to bring it back to normal, for some reason...

Comment: The data is here:
http://www.philadelinquency.com/FULL%20OPA%20AND%20REVENUE%20DUMP%20APR2014%20(REVISED).zip 

I'm working on REVENUE RECORDS.csv now. I'll try trimming the data down if MrFlick's solution doesn't pan out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution using base R's `reshape` function and applied to @MrFlick's sample data. This avoids having to first `melt` your data and `dcast` it to get it into a "wide" format.

```
reshape(data2, direction = "wide", 
        idvar = c("brt_id", "ADDRESS", "OWNERNAME"), 
        timevar = "year")
```

---

Now, regarding your warnings: @MrFlick showed you the way to do this with the "reshape" package (why not "reshape2"? Better to keep updated!) But, he didn't really explain the warnings in his answer.

The first warning is basically telling you that variables that you are trying to put in the "value" column (the measure variables) are different types (some may be character, others may be factors, others may be numeric). In this particular case, "ADDRESS" and "OWNERNAME" (factors) are getting put into the same column with numeric values from teh remaining columns, hence the error. @MrFlick's suggestion to treat those columns as keys even if they might not be would solve *that* problem.

The second warning is a warning that you usually get when the combination of IDs isn't unique. If your data is like the sample data here, and you follow @MrFlick's advice, then you should be OK. Otherwise, you would need to add another column to make the ID variables unique to avoid having `dcast` automatically use `length` as its `fun.aggregate` function.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'm sure it's a problem with the ID variables now.

The first warning is still bound to come up (because the STATUS variable is still a different type than the others), but I'm not worried about this. Now to find my culprits... if only I had bysort...

Comment: Also, the reshape route doesn't seem like it'll work:

    Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1767.1 Gb
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In ans * length(l) : NAs produced by integer overflow
    2: In ans * length(l) + if1 : NAs produced by integer overflow

Comment: One solitary line of >5,000,000 was duplicated inexplicably. Thanks for the heads up about what the warnings mean! A more meaningful message would have helped me get to the root quicker.

Comment: @MichaelChirico, No problem. Did you end up going the "reshape2" or base R `reshape` route? If your data are as large as you describe, I hope you've made the switch to "data.table" already where you'll have access to much faster versions of `dcast` (`dcast.data.table`).

Comment: I'm using reshape2. Not sure why but the reshape function was failing miserably (see above comment).

Had never heard of data.table. The adjustment to R continues! Cut my casting time in half.

Answer (score 3):

Well, using this sample data.frame

```
data2<-data.frame(brt_id=11000600, 
    ADDRESS = "00108-WHARTON-ST",
    OWNERNAME = "PRUSINOWSKI-JOSEPHINE",
    year=2001:2006,
    PRINCIPAL =0,
    INTEREST =0,
    PENALTY =0,
    OTHER =0,
    TOTAL.LIEN.STATUS=0
)
```

Then I think you will find that

```
library(reshape2)
data2m <- melt(data2, id=c("brt_id","ADDRESS","OWNERNAME","year"))
data2c <- dcast(data2m, brt_id+ADDRESS+OWNERNAME+year~...)
```

will produce the original data.frame. The idea is that even though address and owner name are not necessarily part of the key, you want to treat them as such so they don't get melted as well.

And finally, to get it wide by year as you desire, use

```
dcast(data2m, brt_id+ADDRESS+OWNERNAME~...)
```

Comment: I want to upvote this, but I'm torn about whether or not to promote the use of a package that has a clear successor and hasn't really been updated in years. Would you mind updating your answer to use "reshape2" since it's clear the OP is already using that package?

Comment: Good call on including address and owner as ID variables. No luck though! Still replaces every other variable with 1s, and still returns the same errors at each step. I'm thinking there must be an error in the IDs somewhere as @AnandaMahto suggested

Comment: @AnandaMahto OK. I updated to reshape2 (even though I don't really know what the difference is other than more awkwardly named functions)

Comment: @MichaelChirico If you can post a sample data set (in a version we can copy and paste like I did) that reproduces your problem, that would be helpful

Comment: @MrFlick, speed. Actual support in case bugs are found. Thanks for updating :-)

Comment: @MrFlick, I think your sample data recreates both problems stated in the question. There must be more hidden in the actual data... but I don't plan on downloading a 170MB file just to check--unless I get really bored :-)